# solr cannot index attribute/sku in integer

Tags: indexing, search, magento-enterprise, solr

I'm using magento enterprise 1.12, and I found that solr doesnt index and unable to search for some conditons:

**(1) cannot search sku which is in all numbers**

if the sku  is in all numbers (where i found that the field type is text), magento couldnt return correct result.   But if i search this number in solr admin, it returns results.
After investigation , i found that is due to "qt" parameter which generate "qt=magento_zh".
If the searching request contains qt parameter, it search text/fulltext only but not numbers and vice versa. How can i search numbers & text at the same time?

**(2) cannot index integer attribute in solr**
i have an attribute - book_isbn which is all numbers.

In solr, there are 2 relevent indexed columns: attr_book_isbn_zh  , attr_sort_isbn_zh

magento always request to search the first one , which is always empty, it should search the latter one which got value.  Something strange is the situation only happen on this attribute, i have another text attribute "book_author"(same attribute settings) which never get this problem.
So i would like to why solr doesnt index  this column ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?

Comment: I finally find a dirty way to do this, that is to change the schema.xml .
I use "copyField" to copy another column, and then set another "type" for it.
<copyField source="attr_book_isbn_zh" dest="attr_book_isbn_gen"/>
 <field name="attr_book_isbn_gen" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: you could add this as the accepted answer if you like. It may help other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open attributes via admin->catalog->attributes->manage attributes
2. Find attribute which you wish to fix (sku, attr_sort_isbn_zh) and edit it.
3. Set **"Use in Quick Search"** field to **"Yes"**
4. If you want to use it in advanced search, set **"Use in Advanced Search"** field to **"Yes"**
5. Save attribute
6. You should re-index **Product Flat** Data and **Catalog Search Index** via System->Index Management

I test with sku attribute and changed sku of some products to number. Search results are perfect!

Comment: You tested this for a Solr-based index?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention Solr-based search. Tested with standard Magento search functionality.

Comment: Thanks all of you, your suggestion is fine for standard search, but the problem only comes up when using solr